# Clicking all buttons that have the same text with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to automate the process off adding things to a list by clicking the add button and cant figure out how to get selenium to click on every button that has the text "add" on it but not the other buttons.

My end goal is to click add on every anime on the page from my anime list and after every click click the submit button, then once a page is finished go to the next then next letter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findElements` in Selenium returns you the list of web elements that match the locator value, unlike `findElement`, which returns only a single web element. If there are no matching elements within the web page, `findElements` returns an empty list. After that, you can iterate through your list and do the actions.